# array of objects, inside an object, inside array of objects, inside an object ..is empty while it's not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, object, mongoose

I'm working on a project where i have object saved inside of it an array of object called videos like this :
[image]

indside of it, it has an array of objects (videos) as shown, as shown also i have array of objects called PDFs, and here's the problem, when i get the folder Model, the array of PDFs is empty!
the problem is when i get the Video object from the DB, the PDFs array has Data

[image]

as shown, array of PDFs isn't empty, but i can't use it in the user model
also when i try to console.log the folder.video[0].PDFs, "undefined" is printed
so how can invoke it directly whit the folder data?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log video[0].PDFs while your model has field named videos.
Once try logging videos[0].PDFs